# Hexadecimal translation

Tags: html, css, hex, hex-editors

I downloaded a flash player that has changeable settings. I am trying to change the color of the playlist. Problem is...it's using hex's I have never seen before. The existing hex is 0xdadada (for example, the style of hex) and when I tried to change it to #E1E1E1,which is normally a lighter grey, it came out all black.

Does anyone know of a chart or site that translates Oxdadada style hexs to the #E1E1E1 style hex?

Comment: dadada could be hex. that's a light gray. what colour is the play list at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those should be the same. 0xE1E1E1 and #E1E1E1 mean the same thing. **The difference is that in a Flash/Flex stylesheet you need to use the `#` prefix or your colors won't show up**, while elsewhere you are encouraged to use `0x`.

0x prefix, by the way, signals a numerical value, and the hexadecimal value for style colors is a `uint` data type.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same thing, except for one starting with `0x` and the other starting with `#`.

Instead of entering `#E1E1E1` just enter `0xE1E1E1`.

Chances are that the software was looking for a value starting with `0x`, and when it saw yours starting with `#` it defaulted to a numeric value of zero, which of course would be shown as black.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it expects a color string starting with `0x`. Did you try just `0xe1e1e1`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably is the same, but try to keep the same formatting.

However it's possible that the format may be reversed. For instance the HTML format `#RRGGBB` may need to be translated to `0xBBGGRR`, but that will depend on the specifics of the software implementation.